# Is $G\cong H\times G$ means that $H$ is trivial if $G , H$ are groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G , H $ be groups. Suppose $G\cong H\times G$ Is it true that $H$ must be trivial ? 
If $G$ is finite , then I think $H$ is trivial so I'm trying to construct a counterexample when $G$ is infinite.If $G\cong\mathbb{Z}$ how can I find $H$ such that $\mathbb{Z}\cong H\times \mathbb{Z} ?$

Comment: Is there any reason you chose $G=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: No. But if it was $\mathbb{Z}$ Does a nontrivial $H$ exist in this case ?

Comment: No, for $\mathbb{Z}$ the group $H$ would have to be trivial.  Similarly for finite groups it would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider an infinite direct product of a single group $H$.

Comment: Say $H$ is non trivial and $G=H\times H\times H \dots$ (countably many times).  Can you show $G\times H$ is isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: Yes I solved it . Thank you

Comment: No problem, you can accept by clicking the checkmark near my answer if this answered your question.